# Function representation

Tags: calculus, functions, notation

I am learning something about functions. So far I have only seen this kind of a prescription: $f(x)=x^2 + 2$ , for example. I am currently reading a book about functions.

However, this kind of a percription is used in the book: $f:x\to y$ or $f:x\to x^3$.

So the arrow is used there. Can someone explain this percription to me?

Comment: To complement the answer below, the two examples with the arrows are translated to $f(x)=y$ and $f(x)=x^3$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow, which more often has a flat rear end like this $\mapsto$, means 'is mapped to'. Your last example is synonymous with $f(x)=x^3.$

Comment: And what about my first example? The parity of a function is explained on the first example...@Justpassingby

Comment: $$f:x\mapsto x^2+2$$